# What's wrong with this linq query (DBContext)?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm using VS2012, and the DBContext (Entity Framework).

The following query throws an exception

```
Customer cust;
using (var context = new MiniNorthwindContext()) {
    cust = (from c in context.Customers
            where c.CustomerName.Contains("SN")
            select c).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

When I run it, it throws the following error: "Sequence contains more than one element".

If I replace it with

```
Customer cust;
using (var context = new MiniNorthwindContext()) {
    cust = (from c in context.Customers
            where c.CustomerName == "SN Software"
            select c).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Then it passes.

What could I be doing wrong.

Comment: Specifying version of Visual Studio is completely redundant here.
1. The problem is obviously not related to IDE
2. The version of IDE tells almost nothing about version of framework

Comment: Summarizing, you have more than one record that contains the characters "SN", if you just want to grab the first one(which you probably don't) just use FirstOrDefault() instead

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sequence contains more than one element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256757/sequence-contains-more-than-one-element)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can do one of three things:

- if there are no results, return the default;
- if there is one result; return it;
- if there is more than one result, it throws that exception.

So your query is matching more than one row.

Answer (score 1):

[`SingleOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will throw an exception whenever the query returns more than one record. You can use [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead to take the first record if there is any one at all.

Answer (score 0):

Both querys are correct. The problem is the data:

**CUSTOMERNAME**
ESNF CO
SN SOFTWARE
MICROSOFT
APPLE

The first Query (c.CustomerName.Contains("SN")) result:

- ESNF CO
- SN SOFTWARE

Return 2 rows, so that Exception, becouse SingleOrDefault() only allow 1 record.

The second Query (**c.CustomerName == "SN Software"**) result:

- **SN** SOFTWARE

Return only 1 row

Runs perfect !!!.

The problem is the data.