# SingleOrDefault() Throw exception Sequence contains more than one matching element

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

i have dictionary and there are few element has been stored like

```
    Dictionary<string, string> dService = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dService.Add("UPS Express Plus", "001");
    dService.Add("UPS Express Plus", "054");
    dService.Add("UPS Express", "007");
    dService.Add("UPS Express Saver", "065");
    dService.Add("UPS Expedited", "008");
    dService.Add("UPS Express Plus", "001");
```

this way i am trying to get key based on value

```
dService.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Value == ("001")).Key
```

this code is throwing error. i search google and got solution that people saying not to use `SingleOrDefault()` rather use `FirstOrDefault()`

but i got no good explanation why & when `SingleOrDefault()` throw error ? should i presume that dictionary store multiple value that is why `SingleOrDefault()` will not work?

looking for explanation when why & when `SingleOrDefault()` throw error....please guide me sample situation. thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435634/whats-wrong-with-this-linq-query-dbcontext?lq=1

Comment: This does not throw exception.

Comment: "why & when `SingleOrDefault()` throw error" - According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb549274.aspx): [SingleOrDefault] Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence is empty; *this method throws an exception if there is more than one element in the sequence.*

Comment: *this code is throwing error*. What error? This doesn't throw any exception for me. Probably exception is somewhere else..

Comment: You did not provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I bet, your real dictionary contains at least two KeyValuePairs with the value `"001"`.

Comment: yes u r right....i has two 001 in dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your sample-data above does not throw since it doesn't contain multiple equal values which are `"001"`. It would if you'd add two values with `Value="001"`.

If you enumerate a dictionary you get an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. You are asking for the **first and only value** in the dictionary which is `"001"`. Of course a dictionary can contain multiple equal *Values* (but only unique keys).

So you could use `FirstOrDefault` instead which doesn't throw on multiple results. Another way is to find all with `Where`, then `Select` the key:

```
IEnumerable<string> all001ValKeys = dService
    .Where(kv => kv.Value == "001")
    .Select(kv => kv.Key);
```

`SingleOrdefault` (or `Single`) is handy if you want to ensure a business rule like:

```
var record = someTable.Single(obj => obj.ID == 123); // ID must be unique
```

This makes your code more readable and also follows the "failing fast"-rule.

Comment: Also, Single will test every object contained in the list while First will stop at the first matching element.

Comment: @gretro: it won't test _every_ object, it will just check if there's _another one_. That's a differnce since performance should not be a criterion to avoid `Single`/`SingleOrDefault`. Choose what fits best to your business rules.

Answer (score 2):

FirstOrDefault is used if you want first element in list , if no data in list , it will return you default value (which is null) else it will return you first element of list.

SingleOrDefault is used when you are sure only one element in list , if it is not in list , it will return default (which is null), but if it has more then single value , it will throw you exectption.

I hope this explanation is use full for you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `FirstOrDefault` on an Dictionary returns a KeyValuePair containing the default values for the defined Key and Value types. Since you're using string as Key and Value, both will be null. So the result of your LINQ expression will be null and working with the key may result in a NullReferenceException later in your code.

Comment: You're wrong. Go and try it yourself, it will return an KeyValuePair containing the default values for the specified types.

Comment: Your example always returns a result and never default values, since there is no predicate. But `new Dictionary<string, string> { { "A", "001" } }.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "002");` returns a KeyValuePair which itself is NOT null but contains two null values.

Comment: Now i understand your point, `KeyValuePair<Tk, Tv>` is a struct not a class. A `struct` is a value type and always has a (default)value.